# How do i get a simple string from a collection in firebase firestore in an angular project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I'm trying to retrieve a field from firebase firestore in an angular7 project and then store it in a string variable. I need to use the 'where' function but it forces me to use observables and being new to angular I can't figure out the way to extract the desired string.

I've done research that has gotten me to the code provided, but with no success of what I want to accomplish. As an experienced sql developer, this is really frustrating.

```
getUserPrivilegeByUserId(uid:string){
    var data;
     this.db.collection('users', ref => { return ref.where('uid','==',uid)}).snapshotChanges().subscribe(result => {  
      result.forEach(doc =>{
        data = doc.payload.doc.get("privileges");
      })
     }
    );
    return data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with Observables is Asyncronous, so in your example the "return data;" line will be executed long before the "data = doc.payload.doc.get("privileges");" is executed.

**If the getUserPrivilegeByUserId() method lives in a component**, an approach for solving this will be to set data as a property on the component, and then update it in the subscribe, like this:

```
  data: string;

  ...

  getUserPrivilegeByUserId(uid:string){
    this.db.collection('users', ref => { return ref.where('uid','==',uid)}).snapshotChanges().subscribe(result => {  
      result.forEach(doc =>{
        this.data = doc.payload.doc.get("privileges");
      })
     }
    );
  }
```

**If on the other hand the getUserPrivilegeByUserId() method lives in a service**, you could return the Observable from the service like this:

```
  import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

  ...

  getUserPrivilegeByUserId(uid:string): Observable<string>{
    return this.db.collection('users', ref => { return ref.where('uid','==',uid)}).snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(result => {  
          var data;
          result.forEach(doc =>{
            data = doc.payload.doc.get("privileges");
          });
          return data;
         })
      );
```

And then in your component you will do something like:

```
  data: string;

  ...

  this.userService.getUserPrivilegeByUserId(uid).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've completely ignored the asynchronous logic even though I've read it 100 times.